# process to compile a code submitted on an online html form and process it using gcc

Tags: javascript, php, c++, c

Can someone tell me the procedure that i have to follow to make a simple online compiler,which will have:

1)an html page,where the users will write the code.
2)after the submit button has been clicked,it gives out the required output.

here the compilation of c code is done in the background using gcc.
i actually want to know how to execute the whole process,i mean as soon as the code is being written,how do i get it to the compilation loop?

i am quite new to these...please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: Sounds pretty dangerous, I'd think of a sandboxing solution.

Comment: @mastov can you please elaborate your sanboxing solution,how would you execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Most HTTP servers support CGI scripting (the ability to execute an external program).

So, you HTTP server could execute a bash script that compiles and executes the client C program before collecting and displaying its output.

Note that if the C program erases or formats your hard-disk then you will not be able to use this educational tool for very long.